# Python Tkinter text widget index acting weird

Tags: python, indexing, tkinter, text-widget

I am using Tkinter and I am using the text widget with the wrap set to WORD. Which wraps the word when it hits the end if you are still typing it. But when it does do this the row index stays 1 until you hit the enter key. When it should be 2 because it is the second row.

Does anyone know why it does this?
Or
How to fix it?

Comment: Please post OS, Python version, tk version (preferably patchlevel, shown in Idle's Help / About dialog), and the code and procedure you used to observe this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This is just how the tkinter text widget works. The index values are based on logical lines -- lines that end with a newline. Even though the line may wrap visually on the screen, the index won't switch from 1.x to 2.x until the first newline.

Note that when computing an index relative to some other index, you have the option of counting lines by logical lines or display lines. For example, the relative index `"1.0 + 2 display lines"` may result in a different answer than `"1.0 + 2 lines"` depending on if the text is wrapped or not.

Comment: I have tried to use a insert "\n". TO force a new row index but it did not work. Is there any way to force a end line where it will change the row index line?

Comment: Inserting "\n" is how you do it.

Comment: I have tired that but it did not change the row index.

Comment: @0Cool: you must have done something wrong, but since we can't see that code, we can't help.

Comment: I can show you the code on where I am inserting the "\n". Maybe that can help me out some: self.text_field.insert(END, "\n")

Comment: @0Cool: if you do that, it _will_ insert a newline, and the index after that newline _will_ be the next higher "row".